# Notification is only working when App is running on background

Tags: android, android-notifications

I was building a reminder app. In that I added a notification section which will notify the user about the added task. But notification is working only when the app is running in background. When it is closed notification is not working.

I want to get notification when the app is closed too..

ReminderAlarmService.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder;

public class ReminderAlarmService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = ReminderAlarmService.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 42;
    //This is a deep link intent, and needs the task stack
    public static PendingIntent getReminderPendingIntent(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Intent action = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmService.class);
        action.setData(uri);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, action, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public ReminderAlarmService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        Intent action = new Intent(this, AddReminderActivity.class);
        action.setData(uri);
        PendingIntent operation = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(action)
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Grab the task description
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        String description = "";
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                description = AlarmReminderContract.getColumnString(cursor, AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.KEY_TITLE);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        Uri sounduri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String id = "MY_CH_ID";
            CharSequence name = "Product";
            String desc = "Notifications regarding our products";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            mChannel.setDescription(desc);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.setSound(sounduri,attributes);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"MY_CH_ID");
                builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.reminder_title));
                builder.setContentText(description);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_alert_black_24dp);
                builder.setContentIntent(operation);
                builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
                builder.setSound(sounduri);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
                builder.setChannelId("MY_CH_ID");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.remainder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddReminderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_reminder"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"
                />
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name=".AlarmReminderProvider"
            android:authorities="com.droidparkz.reminder"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name=".ReminderAlarmService"
            android:exported="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know why this is happening. Notification is working on my moto e3 power device when app is closed. And in all other devices it fails.

Comment: Show your manifest too

Comment: Maybe you need to add it to the manifest? Please post that as well

Comment: manifest is added.. pls check